# Problema con Fibonacci recursividad

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Hola hace muy poco hemos empezado con recursividad y no lo entiendo mucho, piden crear un programa que haga la sucesion fibonacci pero en varios casos me da otro valor

```
#Fibonacci
def fibonacci(n):
    if n==1 or n ==0:
       return n
    else:
       return fibonacci(n-2)+ fibonacci(n-1)
numero =int (raw_input("Ingrese un numero entero positivo: "))
if numero < 0:
    print("Le dije que era un numero ENTERO POSITIVO")

 i = 0
 print("La sucesion Fibonacci es: ")
 for i in range (0,numero):
    print(fibonacci(i))
```

Ese es mi codigo, si me pudieran decir en que estoy fallando se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de un caso en que no te salga lo que esperas? A mi me parece que está bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se como sería en python, pero me parece que puedes utilizar la lógica del código para lo que requieres (está C).:

```
int x=0,y=1,z=0,i;
for(i=1;i<=13;i++) {
z=y;
y=y+x;
cout<<y<<", ";
x=z;
}
```

Donde y representaría la serie.
ojalá te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me guie en tu respuesta y me dio el resultado :) gracias

Comment: @Wolf Sin embargo esta solución no usa recursividad. No sé si te servirá para tu ejercicio...

Comment: Hola @abulafia tienes razón, pero bueno al final es que tenga por lo menos la ayuda con la lógica, con eso se puede guiar y darle la forma recursiva.